# Pasar un parametro a una pagina usando jquery $.get() de jquery

Tags: php, html, mysql, jquery, ajax

Quiero pasar un parametro(id) de una entrada a actualizar, para ello tengo un enlace que al pulsarlo me lleva a update php. es una pagina que hace una consulta y me muestra datos sobre la entrada. Por el momento lo tengo de esta manera:

```
<th><a href="updateMateria.php?id<?= $nota['id'] ?>" id="entrada-update"><span><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span></a></th>
```

Quiero usar la libreria de jquery y pasar el identificador id a updateMateria.php, para ello encontre en google el metodo `$.get()` de ajax pero no se como implementarlo ya que los datos que se pasan los haria en formato JSON y manualmente.

la funcion que hice es la siguiente:

```
function actualizarEntrada(){
    $.get("actualizarEntrada.php", {nombre: "Evandro", edad: "99"}, function(respuesta){
        $("#consultaInformacion").html(respuesta);
     })
}
$('#entrada-update').on('click', actualizarEntrada);
```

en la linea de $.get(), se pasan los parametro nombre y edad manualmente. quisiera saber como podria pasar el identificador de la entrada para realizar la consulta. 
el html de donde tomo el id es este :

```
    <?php
    require_once '../includes/header.php';
    ?>
    <h2 class=" display-2 text-center text-uppercase text-success">cardex</h2>
    <table class="table my-3 text-center">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Alumno</th>
                <th scope="col">Materia</th>
                <th scope="col">Nota 1</th>
                <th scope="col">Nota 2</th>
                <th scope="col">Nota 3</th>
                <th scope="col">Promedio ACUM.</th>
                <th scope="col">Acion</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $cardex = consultaCardex($conexion);

            if(!empty($cardex)):
                while ($nota = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cardex)):

            ?>

                <tr class="table-light">

                    <th><?= $nota['id'] ?></th>
                    <th><?= $nota['nombre'] ?></th>
                    <th><?= $nota['materia'] ?></th>
                    <th><?= $nota['nota1'] ?></th>
                    <th><?= $nota['nota2'] ?></th>
                    <th><?= $nota['nota3'] ?></th>
                    <th><?= $nota['nota1'] + ($nota['nota2'] + $nota['nota3']) / 3 ?></th>
                    <th><a href="views/actualizarNotas.php?id=<?= $nota['id'] ?>" id="entrada-update"><span><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span></a> | <a href="deleteMateria.php?id<?= $nota['id'] ?>"><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></a></th>
                </tr>
<!-- De acá tomo el id -->
            <?php
                endwhile;
            endif;
             ?>
        </tbody>
        </table>
```

El formulario es este actualizarNotas.php

```
<?php
require_once "../includes/header.php";
//phpinfo();
 $nota = consultaNota($conexion, $_GET['id']) Le mando a la funcion el id que recojo
?>


<div class="container">
<form  action="../controller/atualizarNota.php?id=<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" method="POST" >

        <div class="display-3 text-center text-capitalize text-success">actualiza la nota de <?= $nota['materia'] ?>  del alumno <?= $nota['nombre'] ?> </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="text-white">Nota 1 :</label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg border border-success" type="text" value="<?= $nota['nota1'] ?>" name="nota1" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="text-white">Nota 2 :</label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg border border-success" type="text" value="<?= $nota['nota2'] ?>" name="nota2" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="" class="text-white">Nota 3 :</label>
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg border border-success" type="text" value="<?= $nota['nota3'] ?>" name="nota3" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg">Actualizar</button>
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
```

y donde recojo los datos actualizarNota:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)){
    require_once '../includes/conexion.php';

    $nota1 = isset($_POST['nota1']) ? $_POST['nota1'] : FALSE;
    $nota2 = isset($_POST['nota2']) ? $_POST['nota2'] : FALSE;
    $nota3 = isset($_POST['nota3']) ? $_POST['nota3'] : FALSE;
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : FALSE;
var_dump($nota1,$nota2,$nota3,$id);
die();
    $query = "UPDATE cardex SET nota1 = $nota1, nota2 = $nota2, nota3 = $nota3 WHERE id = $id";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conexion));

    if($result){
        $_SESSION['message'] = '<p class="aletr-success">Se ha actualizado la nota del alumno correctamente</p>';
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = '<p class="aletr-danger">hubo un error en la actualización de la nota</p>';
        header('location: ../index.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar más información, específicamente, el HTML de donde quieres tomar los datos.

Comment: Actualize  la pregunta, añadi la pagina de donde tomo el id y lo pasa a actualizarNotas. php, ahí manda los datos nota1, nota2 y nota3 junto con el id a actualizarNota. php para tratarlos.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacer algo así;

```
<th><a href="updateMateria.php?id<?= $nota['id'] ?>" data-id="$nota['id']" id="entrada-update"><span><i class="far fa-edit"></i></span></a></th>
```

Y luego capturas con jquery;

```
var id = $( "#entrada-update" ).data( "id" );
```

Para mas referncias https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: Gracias por responder definitivamente por ahi es, si hago var_dump($_get['id']) a la pagina donde quiero pasar el identificador, sale Undefined. Seguire buscando la forma